# Maintaining a HTML session with a cookie SID JSOUP

Tags: android, cookies, authentication, jsoup

I'm working on an android application which logs into a website. Basically I have managed to login within Activity A. The user is then redirected to activity B, I want to maintain that logged in session while in activity B. In order to achieve this I have tried this:

```
        Document postLogin = Jsoup.connect("http://forums.d2jsp.org/")
                .cookie("sid", sidDetails.getSid())
                .post();
```

As you can see i'm trying to POST the cookie SID. This obviously isn't working, so does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this? It should be noted I am using JSOUP.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough here to go on. You need to figure out what the site is using to maintain login state, and make sure you're setting up Jsoup to send that data.

What I would suggest is that you use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to trace the requests you make in a regular browser to this site, then make sure you're setting up Jsoup to send the right data. By watching the HTTP traffic over the wire, you'll get a better picture of what's happening, and hopefully spot what's missing.

If you can't see how to get Jsoup to add the right data to the request, just give an example of what you need.

Comment: Hey friend,

Through your advice I have come to realise that after logging in 3 values are required to maintain the session, these being, the session ID (sid), a member id, and something call msec (what is this?).

I can access all of these, my question now is, what do I do with them? I attach the SID just as i've shown in my code above, but how do I attach the msec and member_id?

Comment: Is that other data also sent as cookies? You can just stack them up with extra calls, like `.cookie("memberId", memberId)`. (msec sounds maybe like milliseconds -- used for time since login, perhaps?)